# librarian-puppet v2.1.0 switch git branch in Puppetfile

Tags: puppet

I am using `librarian-puppet` `v2.1.0` with the following puppet file:

```
mod "team/app", 
    :git => "git@github.com:myTeam/puppet-repo.git",
    :branch => 'weblegacy'
```

When I try to install puppet I get `unrecognized options: branch`.

What is the syntax for switching branching in a `Puppetfile` in version `2.1.0`?

Comment: librarian-puppet was basically superseded by r10k about four years ago. Your `Puppetfile` would work as expected within r10k.

Comment: yes, I know this is an older version of Puppet, but for a variety of reasons I need to use the older version.  I would like help getting 2.1.0 to work.

Comment: The version of Puppet you are using is irrelevant for this.

Comment: @MattSchuchard what does that mean?  I am getting an error trying to use a particular version of librarian puppet, and I am looking for help on the syntax to correct my puppet file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```rb
mod "team/app", 
    :git => "git@github.com:myTeam/puppet-repo.git",
    :ref => 'weblegacy'
```

or if you want to specify a version:

```rb
mod "team/app", 
    :git => "git@github.com:myTeam/puppet-repo.git",
    :tag => 'v1.0.0'
```

More about the `Puppetfile` syntax on the [official docs](https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.3/puppetfile.html#keep-repository-content-at-a-specific-version)